# Install rpm package on amazon-linux-2 EC2 instance offline

Tags: amazon-ec2, offline, rpm, yum, rstudio-server

I'm trying to install an rpm package (rstudio-server) on an amazon-linux-2 EC2 instance that is not connected to the internet by uploading all its dependencies. I'm largely following the instructions from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259640/how-to-use-yum-to-get-all-rpms-required-for-offline-use).

## With amazon-linux-2 docker image

On my local machine, in the [amazonlinux docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/amazonlinux), I run:

```
mkdir /var/tmp/rstudio-server
mkdir /var/tmp/rstudio-server-installroot
wget https://download2.rstudio.org/server/centos7/x86_64/rstudio-server-rhel-1.4.1106-x86_64.rpm
yum install --downloadonly --installroot=/var/tmp/rstudio-server-installroot/ --downloaddir=/var/tmp/rstudio-server rstudio-server-rhel-1.4.1106-x86_64.rpm --releasever latest
```

I get this error:

```
Loaded plugins: ovl, priorities
Repository 'amzn2-core': Error parsing config: Error parsing "mirrorlist = '$awsproto://$amazonlinux.$awsregion.$awsdomain/latest/$product/$target/x86_64/mirror.list'": URL must be http, ftp, file or https not ""
Repository 'amzn2-core-source': Error parsing config: Error parsing "mirrorlist = '$awsproto://$amazonlinux.$awsregion.$awsdomain/latest/$product/$target/SRPMS/mirror.list'": URL must be http, ftp, file or https not ""
Repository 'amzn2-core-debuginfo': Error parsing config: Error parsing "mirrorlist = '$awsproto://$amazonlinux.$awsregion.$awsdomain/latest/$product/$target/debuginfo/x86_64/mirror.list'": URL must be http, ftp, file or https not ""
Examining rstudio-server-rhel-1.4.1106-x86_64.rpm: rstudio-server-1.4.1106-1.x86_64
Marking rstudio-server-rhel-1.4.1106-x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package rstudio-server.x86_64 0:1.4.1106-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: sqlite for package: rstudio-server-1.4.1106-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: postgresql-libs for package: rstudio-server-1.4.1106-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: psmisc for package: rstudio-server-1.4.1106-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: rstudio-server-1.4.1106-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: rstudio-server-1.4.1106-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: rstudio-server-1.4.1106-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: rstudio-server-1.4.1106-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: rstudio-server-1.4.1106-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: rstudio-server-1.4.1106-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: rstudio-server-1.4.1106-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: rstudio-server-1.4.1106-1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: rstudio-server-1.4.1106-1.x86_64 (/rstudio-server-rhel-1.4.1106-x86_64)
           Requires: sqlite
Error: Package: rstudio-server-1.4.1106-1.x86_64 (/rstudio-server-rhel-1.4.1106-x86_64)
           Requires: /bin/sh
Error: Package: rstudio-server-1.4.1106-1.x86_64 (/rstudio-server-rhel-1.4.1106-x86_64)
           Requires: postgresql-libs
Error: Package: rstudio-server-1.4.1106-1.x86_64 (/rstudio-server-rhel-1.4.1106-x86_64)
           Requires: psmisc
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

If I try running it without the `--installroot` flag, it creates just two other rpm files, `postgresql-libs` and `psmisc`. I assume these are the direct dependencies, but it does not install the second-order dependencies. Trying to run the same command on the dependencies does nothing.

## With CentOS docker image

If I try it in a [centos docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos), I can build the repo, but it doesn't seem to work from the other side.

```
mkdir /var/tmp/rstudio-server
mkdir /var/tmp/rstudio-server-installroot
wget https://download2.rstudio.org/server/centos7/x86_64/rstudio-server-rhel-1.4.1106-x86_64.rpm
yum install --downloadonly --installroot=/var/tmp/rstudio-server-installroot/ --downloaddir=/var/tmp/rstudio-server rstudio-server-rhel-1.4.1106-x86_64.rpm --releasever 8
```

This creates 167 files under `/var/tmp/rstudio-server`.

I upload them all, as well as the original `rstudio-server` rpm, to the remote machine (through a special S3 bucket that does a virus scan and moves it to another S3 bucket), then download everything to `/var/tmp/rstudio-server` on the amazon-linux-2 EC2 machine.

I then create a file called `/etc/yum.repos.d/offline-rstudio-server.repo`, with the following contents:

```
[offline-rstudioserver]
name=amazon-linux-2 - rstudioserver
baseurl=file:///var/tmp/rstudio-server
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-amazon-linux-2
```

I then run:

```
sudo yum --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=offline-rstudioserver install /var/tmp/rstudio-server/rstudio-server-rhel-1.4.1106-x86_64.rpm
```

It gives me many messages like:

```
--> Processing Dependency: libgnutils.so.28()(64bit) for package: neon-0.30.0-3.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
```

And then, many messages like:

```
Error: Package: python3-libs-3.7.6-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 (@amzn2-core)
           Requires: libtirpc.so.1()(64bit)
           Removing: libtirpc-0.2.4-0.16.amzn2.x86_64 (@amzn2-core)
               libtirpc.so.1()(64bit)
           Updated by: libtirpc-1.1.4-4.el8.x86_64 (offline-rstudioserver)
              ~libtirpc.so.3()(64bit)
```

I assume the problem here is that I'm compiling it on a CentOS machine and bringing it to an amazon-linux-2 machine, and there's some fundamental incompatibility there.

I am officially stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: Doing it offline, you have to have the main package and also all dependency packages. You can download all on the internet machine and copy them over to the offline machine.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Howdi

It looks to me that your amazon linux install has provided libtirpc at a higher version that your offline repo. via a dependancy of python3-libs

Since you are working offline and wont be getting conflicting updates from internet, here is something you could try to 'get things running' , I dont recommend this as a production method :P

```
rpm -e --justdb --nodeps libtirpc-0.2.4-0.16.amzn2.x86_64
```

This would have the effect of removing the entries for this package from rpm db, letting yum feel ok about continuing, whilst not actually deleting anything from the package on the file system ( which if it had, would probably break things )

There maybe other dependancies, that could complicate things. Good luck.